# History - age - of Sousaphone with brand "Symphonic"?

Tags: brass, sousaphone

Our band is using an old Sousaphone which still produces a nice deep round tone. The brand "symphonic" and history (serial number 613635) however is unknown. Many musicians asked us about the origin and manufacturer of the Sousaphone.
Does anyone know the brand?
Can anyone point us to information to trace its history?

[image: Entire Sousaphone]
[image: Tubes]
[image: Serial number]
[image: Symphonic]

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: Europe, Netherlands

Comment: I wonder if "Symphonic" is the model name rather than the manufacturer.   BTW, if you can get a high-contrast photo of the region with "symphonic" and the artwork, you could try Google Image Search